# Meteor - Mongo aggregate does not have $count stage

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate) package to do Mongo aggregation in Meteor. I want to get the count at the last stage of the pipeline so I use this code:

```
Message.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // ...
    }
  }, {
    $count: 'count'
  }
]);
```

It is pretty simple and should work, but I only get this error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'methodname' 
MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$count'
...
```

Please help, thanks.

**Updated**: this question is not duplicated as an editor suggested, my main intention is to find out why I can not use `$count`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`$count` is available in mongodb version 3.4. For previous versions, 
you will need to use `$group` over a constant field.

```
Message.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // ...
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id : null, 
      count : {$sum : 1}
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer though it is not what I am looking for. I am well aware that I could use `$group` to finish the job, the thing is I just wonder why I could not use `$count` despite the fact that it does exist

Comment: `$count` aggregation pipeline was introduced in version 3.4. Which version are you using? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27335

Comment: oh I see, my bad I did not notice `$count` is only available in 3.4. Thank so much, also please edit your answer I will mark it as the right answer

Comment: For future people: I thought I was using a new-enough version of mongo because my package.json for mongoose was 4.12.4, but the version of mongodb was still 3.2.20